# Disable Keyboard through Python on OS X (without root)

Tags: python, macos, keyboard, root

Through a Python script, how can one completely disable or ignore keyboard input on OS X, preferably without root access and external libraries?  I'm not sure a script like so is plausible, or even possible, but any and all help is much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the context of this? disable its system wide whilst running, or just ignore it in the python program

Comment: Preferably, system-wide while the script is running.

Comment: without root I'm going to say you can't, but if you don't mind using a shell command from python, this page has the commands to do it http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=433407